# PreloadJS tag loading instead of xhr

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, createjs, preloadjs

I am using [preloadjs](http://createjs.com/docs/preloadjs/modules/PreloadJS.html) for large asset loading.
I am using lots of js libraries like 60+ jquery plugins.
I just want a nice loader that displays progress of assets loading with progress bar and listing file which were loaded successfully and which were failed.

- I am using simple example to display my problem.
- Previously I was using `new createjs.LoadQueue(true)` to load content using **XHR** But I find XHR very slow as compared to old-fashioned  tags to load scripts. 
  As per doc, I want to switch to load content using **tag-based loading** instead of XHR but I cant figure out how. Please see the code below

**Objective:**

1. How to use tag-based loading  ??
2. Is it true that old-fashioned `<script>`tags will load scripts faster than preloadjs XHR

**CODE:**

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <title>preloadjs </title>
    <script src="https://code.createjs.com/preloadjs-0.6.2.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
    <script id="1" type="text/javascript"></script>
    <script id="2" type="text/javascript"></script>
    <script id="3" type="text/javascript"></script>
    <script id="4" type="text/javascript"></script>
    <script id="5" type="text/javascript"></script>
</head>
<body>
    <div id="progress"> </div>
    <script type="text/javascript">
        //
        var manifest = [{
            "src": "https://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.12.4.min.js",
            "id": "1"
        }, {
            "src": "https://code.jquery.com/ui/1.11.3/jquery-ui.min.js",
            "id": "2"
        }, {
            "src": "https://code.jquery.com/ui/1.11.3/FAIL-IT.js",
            "id": "3"
        }, {
            "src": "https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/flot/0.8.3/jquery.flot.min.js",
            "id": "4"
        }, {
            "src": "https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/Chart.js/2.2.1/Chart.min.js",
            "id": "5"
        }];
        //
        var queue = new createjs.LoadQueue(false);
        queue.setMaxConnections(5);
        queue.maintainScriptOrder = true;
        queue.on('progress', function(event) {
            //fired when the overall progress changes
            var value = queue.progress.toFixed(2) * 100;
            document.getElementById('progress').innerHTML = value + '%';
        });
        queue.on('complete', function(event) {
            //fired when the entire queue has been loaded
            document.getElementById('progress').innerHTML = '100% - all done';
        });
        queue.on('error', function(event) {
            console.log(event);
        });
        queue.loadManifest(manifest);
    </script>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: I answered this here: https://github.com/CreateJS/PreloadJS/issues/212

Answer (score 0):

After viewing your post, I have done some tests and realized that, when using

```
createjs.LoadQueue(false);
```

content is loaded as tags on HEADER section, so, the following code

```
loader = new createjs.LoadQueue(false);
loader.loadManifest([
            { type: createjs.AbstractLoader.CSS, src: '/node_modules/material-design-icons/iconfont/material-icons.css'},
            { type: createjs.AbstractLoader.CSS, src: '/node_modules/materialize-css/dist/css/materialize.css'},
            { type: createjs.AbstractLoader.CSS, src: '/styles.css'},
            { type: createjs.AbstractLoader.JAVASCRIPT, src: 'https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.4/jquery.min.js' }
        ]);
```

will just create the following on

```
<head>
<meta charset="UTF-8">
<title>Title</title>
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="/node_modules/material-design-icons/iconfont/material-icons.css">
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="/node_modules/materialize-css/dist/css/materialize.css">
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="/styles.css">
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.4/jquery.min.js"></script>
</head>
```

Hope this helps with you first question.